# How can I get the most recent unique record out of a table not in 1NF?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am attempting to create a query that will return an employee's name, department, supervisor, and current status. However, the table in question contains historical records and well as current records of each employee, including a record for each supervisor they have had, each department, etc.

How can I get the most recent record for each employee? I have tried to simply select the MAX(Effective_Date) column, to only pull the last record. However, this does not always work with the dataset, as each record has an ID for the employee, as well as an ID for the *record*.

Here's an example of the full table setup: [Filedropper.com/exampledata](http://www.filedropper.com/exampledata)

And here's an example of the current code I have.

```
use ws_er;
select
od.Master_org_dim_id
,od.Member_Last_Name + ', ' + od.Member_First_Name as [Associate Name]
,od.Member_Role as [Tier]
,od.Member_Status as [Status]
,sod.member_last_name + ', ' + sod.member_First_name as [Supervisor Name]
,MAX(od.Effective_Date) as [Effective Date]
,COUNT(od.Master_org_dim_id) as [count]

from Organization_Dim as od
inner join organization_dim as sod on sod.org_dim_id = od.supervisor_dim_id

group by
od.Master_org_dim_id
,od.Member_Last_Name + ', ' + od.Member_First_Name
,od.Member_Role
,od.Member_Status
,sod.member_last_name + ', ' + sod.member_First_name

order by [associate name] desc
```

Comment: Post the table design.  Don expect us to go to a linked source..

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't sure of the right way to put the table design in the text. I'll adjust that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
( select * 
       , row_number() over (partition by od.Master_org_dim_id,    
                                         od.Member_Last_Name,   
                                         od.Member_First_Name 
                                order by od.Effective_Date desc) as rn 
       , count(od.Master_org_dim_id) over (partition by od.Master_org_dim_id,  
                                                        od.Member_Last_Name,  
                                                        od.Member_First_Name) as count
from Organization_Dim 
) odr
join organization_dim as sod 
  on sod.org_dim_id = odr.supervisor_dim_id
 and odr.rn = 1
```

But this is just an less then fully undefined condition

```
on sod.org_dim_id = odr.supervisor_dim_id
```

I suspect you are going to need to get fancy and determine the supervisor on the date but this should get you started.  Even with that you could return zero or more supervisor.

If an employee name was entered differently this breaks.  I don't need to tell you this data design is not optimal.

Comment: I think you need a `count(od.Master_org_dim_id) over (partition by od.Master_org_dim_id, od.Member_Last_Name, od.Member_First_Name) as count` in your inner query to get all the data she is looking for.

Comment: @BaconBits I think I agree

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a subquery where you get the max date per employee ID, and then use the date to that subquery. Something like this:

```
use ws_er;
select
od.Master_org_dim_id
,od.Member_Last_Name + ', ' + od.Member_First_Name as [Associate Name]
,od.Member_Role as [Tier]
,od.Member_Status as [Status]
,sod.member_last_name + ', ' + sod.member_First_name as [Supervisor Name]
,mxd.EffectiveDate as [Effective Date]
,COUNT(od.Master_org_dim_id) as [count]

from Organization_Dim as od
inner join organization_dim as sod on sod.org_dim_id = od.supervisor_dim_id
inner join (select Master_org_dim_id, max(Effective_Date) EffectiveDate from Organization_Dim group by Master_org_dim_id) as mxd
on od.Master_org_dim_id = mxd.Master_org_dim_id

group by
od.Master_org_dim_id
,od.Member_Last_Name + ', ' + od.Member_First_Name
,od.Member_Role
,od.Member_Status
,sod.member_last_name + ', ' + sod.member_First_name
,mxd.EffectiveDate

order by [associate name] desc
```

Untested, but should do the trick, or at least point you to the right direction